# Preload an image asset in flutter

Tags: memory-leaks, dart, flutter

I'm building a game with flutter. I have around 130-150mo of pictures. And some of them *must* be preloaded or else the user experience doesn't feels smooth.

I found by myself a way to preload images :

```
final asset = new ExactAssetImage(assetPath);
final stream = asset.resolve(createLocalImageConfiguration(context));
```

While this works, there's a huge drawback : The memory cost is about 6 times bigger then the actual image size.

Consequence ? My app end up consuming 800 MO of ram just by loading images, which is insane (especially considering it's a relatively simple app).
In fact the ram consumption is so big that I get tons of frame lost.

So in short :
What is the most ideal way to preload an image ? Is there something I missed ?

Comment: Have you solved this problem?

Comment: If you know when they are going to be used then perhaps you don't need to preload all of them and you can just load them before they are needed and destroy them once you are done with them?

Comment: May I ask why you cannot use precacheimage class?
https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/precacheImage.html
this question seems like a duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51343735/flutter-image-preload/51343954#51343954

Comment: This did not exist

Comment: @RémiRousselet Even with `precacheImage`, images take 6x more memory than their size. Have you found a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the UX to feel smooth then you can use `FadeInImage()` and give it an asset image to use as placeholder until the final image loads, and if you want to fade in image from a transparent background then you can use the [transparent_image](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/transparent_image) package.