# Flutter image preload

Tags: dart, flutter

Is it possible to preload somehow the image on the app start? Like I have an background image in my drawer but for the first time when I open the drawer I can see the image blinks like it is fetched from assets and then displayed and it gives bad experience to me once I see it for the first time other openings of the drawer are behaving as expected because it is cached. I would like to prefetch it on the app load so there is no such effect.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Use the [`precacheImage`](https://docs.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/precacheImage.html) function to start loading an image before your drawer is built. For example, in the widget that contains your drawer:

```
class MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    // Adjust the provider based on the image type
    precacheImage(new AssetImage('...'));
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

}
```

Comment: In my case the precacheImage method need the context:  precacheImage(new AssetImage('...'), context);

Comment: This helps a lot, but it seems the image will get kicked out of the cache after a lot of other images have been loaded. Is there a way to keep it in the cache permanently?

Comment: @Aurast you can set `imageCache.maximumSize`, however be wary of going out of memory especially on devices with low RAM.

Comment: Thanks @mertcanb that helps, was hoping there might be a way to keep a specific image cached, since there's really only one I wanted to keep in memory (the drawer menu banner). But I guess that's probably not possible.

Comment: `precacheImage` should be called in `didChangeDependencies()` because it needs a `BuildContext` that allows media queries. Calling it in `initState()` may cause unhandled exceptions etc. See @Ethirallan's answer

Comment: It should indeed be called inside `didChangeDependencies()`, otherwise it causes errors in flutter >3.0.0. Please, change this answer

Answer (score 48):

I had problems with the upper solution which uses precacheImage() inside initState. The code below resolved them. Also note that you might not see expected results in the debug mode but only in the release mode.

```
Image myImage;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    myImage= Image.asset(path);
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    precacheImage(myImage.image, context);
  }
```

Comment: It really helps if the widget is stateful. If stateless it is possible to precache before creating the widget

Answer (score 23):

There is a good article on this subject : https://alex.domenici.net/archive/preload-images-in-a-stateful-widget-on-flutter

It should look something like this

```
class _SampleWidgetState extends State<SampleWidget> {
  Image image1;
  Image image2;
  Image image3;
  Image image4;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    image1 = Image.asset("assets/image1.png");
    image2 = Image.asset("assets/image2.png");
    image3 = Image.asset("assets/image3.png");
    image4 = Image.asset("assets/image4.png");
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();

    precacheImage(image1.image, context);
    precacheImage(image2.image, context);
    precacheImage(image3.image, context);
    precacheImage(image4.image, context);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
          child: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              image1,
              image2,
              image3,
              image4,
            ],
          ),
        );
  }
}
```

Comment: This answer is already provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56265182/12483095).  Let me know what new relevant information you added to it.

Comment: @iDecode I think my answer is more readable

Comment: I can also modify your answer to look it more readable but will that be actually good practice on Stack Overflow, of course not.

Answer (score 9):

To get rid of the "blink", you can simply use the [`FadeInImage` class](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/FadeInImage-class.html) in combination with [`transparent_image`](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/transparent_image#-installing-tab-), which will fade instead of appearing instantly. Usage, in your case, looks as follow:

```
// you need to add transparent_image to your pubspec and import it
// as it is required to have the actual image fade in from nothing
import 'package:transparent_image/transparent_image.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

...
  FadeInImage(
    placeholder: MemoryImage(kTransparentImage),
    image: AssetImage('image.png'),
  )
```

Comment: This does not actually answer the question that was asked

Comment: @JonahWilliams I think so because most of the question consists of the "blink" effect as a whole, even though the title does not suggest that: "so there is no such effect" is what I tried to answer.

Comment: Ye this does not answer the question. I need the image to be instantly loaded no fading no blinking. Just open drawer with already cached image something like this.

Comment: Exactly what I needed.

Comment: what is `kTransparentImage`

Comment: @Bawantha it comes with `package:transparent_image/transparent_image.dart`

Comment: You will need to add to your `pubspec.yaml dependencies`:
  `transparent_image: ^1.0.0`

Answer (score 6):

The `precacheImage()` function *(as used in most of the answers)* returns a `Future`, and for certain use case scenarios it can be really useful. For instance, in my app I needed to load an external image and like everyone else did not want to experience the flickering. So I ended up with something like this:

```
// show some sort of loading indicator
...

precacheImage(
    NetworkImage(),
    context,
).then((_) {
    // replace the loading indicator and show the image
    // (may be with some soothing fade in effect etc.)
    ...
});
```

Please note that, in the above example I wanted to illustrate how the `Future` can be potentially used. The comments are just to help express the idea. Actual implementation has to be done in a `Fluttery` way.

Answer (score 4):

All the replies about didChangeDependencies() are unuseful at all for splashscreen.
At this link you can find the right solution for very first screen preload and in general if you want to handle the preload with await: https://gist.github.com/AngDrew/569bdd51742687d5526a8257b7f1eb8f
Many many thanks to the original dev AngDrew

Comment: how can i use it for any screen. i am passing url to my grid view screen

Answer (score 2):

I had the following problem: image requires some space. So after loading, it pushed UI down which is not good for UX. I decided to create a builder to display an empty (or loading) container until the image is loaded and after that display my UI.

Looks like `precacheImage` returns future which is resolved. The tricky part for me was `FutureBuilder` and `snapshot.hasData` which was always `false` because future is resolved with `null`. So I added future transformation to fix `snapshot.hasData`:

```
precacheImage(this.widget.imageProvider, context).then((value) => true)
```

I'm not sure is it ok to call `precacheImage` multiple times so I decided to wrap it into `StatefulWidget`.

You can check the final builder [here](https://gist.github.com/fedotxxl/aa03b152fdc2e3c5d3573e2a656acfb2)

Use builder the following way:

```
return PreloadingImageBuilder(
      imageProvider: AssetImage("assets/images/logo-main.png"),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return Scaffold(
            ...
          );
        } else {
          return Container();
        }
      },
    );
```

Comment: Hi @fedor.belov, does this really preload the image before calling build() method? 

Normally, to get the advantage of precacheImage (which is loading before rendering), the precacheImage is declared in didChangeDependencies for example. However, here you are calling it already in the build...

Comment: @Jorge I Think you are right. Since this would be part of the  `build()` method, no actual pre-loading will occur. It will simply delay building the Scaffold until the image is loaded and the Future returned by AssetImage has completed. This may however be enough to avoid flicker cause by the image arriving late

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your logic and UX, something like this can work too (when pushing a new route with images):

```
Future.wait([
                precacheImage(AssetImage("assets/imageA.png"), context),
            ]).then((value) {
                Navigator.pop(context);
                Navigator.pushReplacement(
                    context,
                    YourRouteRoute()
              );
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
late AssetImage assetImage;

 @override
 void initState() {
    assetImage = const AssetImage("$kImagePath/bkg2.png");
    super.initState();
 }

 @override
 void didChangeDependencies() {
    precacheImage(assetImage, context);
    super.didChangeDependencies();
 }
```