# flutter preload image of list

Tags: image, caching, flutter, preload

My flutter app would like to show image from firebase by calling image.network(). But the images displaying late a bit.
Please kindly help to solve this issue. How to preload the images or save images into cache in advance?

```
child: ListTile(
                leading: Image.network(
                  food.thumbnail,
                  width: 60.0,
                ),
                title: Text(
                    food.foodName + "     " + '\$' + food.foodPrice.toString()),
                subtitle: Text('編碼： ' + food.foodCode),
                onTap: () {}),
```

updated:

```
child: ListTile(
                leading:
                Image(image: new CachedNetworkImageProvider(food.thumbnail),
                width: 60.0,),

                title: Text(
                    food.foodName + "     " + '\$' + food.foodPrice.toString()),
                subtitle: Text('編碼： ' + food.foodCode),
                onTap: () {}),
          ),
```

Please see my update that using CachedNetworkImageProvider, The image are also displaying late. I think I made some mistake. Please kindly help.

Comment: Check out either the [flutter_advanced_networkimage](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_advanced_networkimage) or [cached_network_image](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/cached_network_image) packages.

Comment: Please see my update and help.

Comment: Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51343954/7448506)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For cases like this, there is a Widget in flutter which comes out of the box and it is called `FadeInImage`. You can use it like this:

```
FadeInImage(
  height: 200.0, // Change it to your need
  width: 300.0, // Change it to your need
  fit: BoxFit.cover,
  placeholder: AssetImage("assets/company_logo.jpg"),
  image: NetworkImage(your_image_url),
),
```

The important property here is the `placeHolder`, you can use any offline image stored in Assets like your company logo and when the images loads this will fade out and fresh image will fade in leading to a nice UX.

Comment: the placeholder image size is always changed using cover fit !

Answer (score 0):

[shimmer](https://pub.dev/packages/shimmer) package is a good solution for preloading a shimmer effect

[image]