# flutter asset image splash while scrolling

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

In listview when scroll asset image splashing. 
Looks like it's re-render images. For network image it's working fine. Issue with local images.

Here is issue [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/beyGF.gif).

Here is `ListView` code. These code directly applied inside `Scaffold` class.

```
ListView.builder(
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return  Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0),
      height: 200.0,
      child: Image.asset(
        "images/${index + 1}.jpg",
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      ),
    );
  },
  itemCount: 10,
)
```

Comment: What is the size of the image?

Comment: height : 1440 width : 2560 @SagarTamang But it's working in `Image.network`.

Comment: Try compressing and loading the images. https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_image_compress

Comment: Check this one : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51343735/flutter-image-preload