# Cache base64 string of images in flutter

Tags: flutter, caching, base64, bloc

I am creating chat app with flutter and I use base64 string for images and also use bloc.
My problem is when list of chat messages update, images flickering. and this is very annoying that images rerender every time. So I think with cache images this may be solve.
What should I do for this?

Image Widget:

```
class ImageBox extends StatelessWidget {
  final String imgSrc;
  final String defaultImg;
  final BoxFit boxFit;
  ImageBox({
    @required this.imgSrc,
    @required this.defaultImg,
    this.boxFit = BoxFit.fill,
  });
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return imgSrc == null || imgSrc.isEmpty
        ? Image.asset(
            defaultImg,
            fit: boxFit,
          )
        : Image.memory(
            base64Decode(imgSrc),
            fit: boxFit,
          );
  }
}
```

part of widget to show image:

```
GestureDetector(
    onTap: () async {
        await showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (_) => ImageDialog(
                img: chatMessage.message,
            ),
        );
    },
    child: Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.4,
        child: ImageBox(
            imgSrc: chatMessage.message,
            defaultImg: Assets.avatar,
        ),
    ),
),
```

bloc state for holding list:

```
class DataLoaded extends ChatState {
  final List<ChatMessage> chatMessages;
  DataLoaded({this.chatMessages});
}
```

update list in bloc:

```
Stream<ChatState> _mapAddToMessagesEventToState(ChatMessage chatMessage) async* {
    List<ChatMessage> chatMessages = (state as DataLoaded).chatMessages;
    chatMessages.insert(0, chatMessage);
    print(chatMessages);
    yield DataLoaded(chatMessages: chatMessages);
}
```

ChatMessage model:

```
class ChatMessage {
  ChatMessageType chatMessageType;
  String message;
  DateTime dateTime;
  int userId;
  ChatMessage({
    @required this.chatMessageType,
    @required this.message,
    @required this.dateTime,
    @required this.userId,
  });
}
```

and My ChatScreen:

```
class ChatScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final int chatId;
  ChatScreen({@required this.chatId});
  final ChatRepository chatRepository = ChatRepository();

  Widget createBody(ChatState state, BuildContext context) {
    if (state is Loading) {
      return SkeletonListLoading();
    } else if (state is DataLoaded) {
      return Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          MessagesList(
            messages: state.chatMessages,
          ),
          SendBar(
            onMessage: (message) => BlocProvider.of<ChatBloc>(context).add(
              AddToMessages(
                chatMessage: ChatMessage(
                  chatMessageType: ChatMessageType.TEXT,
                  dateTime: DateTime.now(),
                  message: message,
                  userId: store.state.userProfile.id,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            onImage: (img) => BlocProvider.of<ChatBloc>(context).add(
              AddToMessages(
                chatMessage: ChatMessage(
                  chatMessageType: ChatMessageType.IMAGE,
                  dateTime: DateTime.now(),
                  message: img,
                  userId: store.state.userProfile.id,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      );
    } else {
      return Container();
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider<ChatBloc>(
      create: (context) {
        return ChatBloc(chatRepository: chatRepository)..add(ChatScreenOpened(chatId: chatId));
      },
      child: BlocListener<ChatBloc, ChatState>(
        listener: (context, state) async {},
        child: BlocBuilder<ChatBloc, ChatState>(
          builder: (context, state) {
            return Scaffold(
              body: createBody(state, context),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: did you check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/51343954/9142279?

Comment: How can I used in when I have list of images?

Comment: and also how pass base64 string to it?

Comment: To use it with list of images I think you can loop on the list , but to pass base64 string that I don't know, I thought you are open to idea of giving up base64 Strings and using image path/source directly

Comment: No I have base64 string of image. and as I said I have bloc and initState called once, so loop works only once.