# How to avoid Image Area showing Blue before Loading App

Tags: flutter

I am loading a rectangle logo saved as a .jpg into a CircleAvatar in my App.

When I am restarting my App, the area where the logo is loading appears blue for a few seconds. Then the real logo appears.

This Widget is found within a Stack.

This is how I transform my 1080x1073 image into a round logo within Flutter.

```
 Container(
                width: size.width * 0.5,
                height: size.width * 0.5,
                child: CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/images/logo.jpg'),
                ),
              ),
```

Does this happen because my image is too big? How should I handle this problem?

P.S. I am testing this on Visual Studio Code.

Answer (score 2):

By default the background color is set to blue, you can modify the property and it will show whatever color you assign to it.

```
              Container(
                width: size.width * 0.5,
                height: size.width * 0.5,
                child: CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.red, //here
                  backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/images/logo.jpg'),
                ),
              ),
```

Comment: I appreciate the workaround. Is there still no alternative to not seeing this at all?

Comment: Not really, it depends on how much time it takes to load that image and render to the screen, flutter has to assign some space for the incoming image and that's what this space(color) is for. I'd suggest using an image of smaller res or compressing it before passing it so it loads faster.

Answer (score 2):

This has more to do with the delay it takes to load an image. You can change the background color like Yudhishthir suggested if the color is the actual problem or you can pre-fetch the image so that the image loads before anything is built.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51343954/6514318) describes how to do the image pre-fetch using the `precacheImage` function.

Comment: Thanks for adding further, yes that's a legit way. :)

Comment: Its my pleasure. :)

Answer (score 2):

This Cookbook solution is designed for this situation. Just replace the CircularProgressIndicator with whatever you want to show before the image is loaded.

https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/images/fading-in-images

Comment: Is that really you Scott?

Comment: This is a nice workaround, although it is impossible to use within a CircleAvatar for the backgroundImage parameter to my understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Had similar blue background then changed to InkWell:

```
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: () async {
          myFunc();
        },
        child: Container(
          width: 50,
          height: 50,
          clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(shape: BoxShape.circle),
          child: Image.asset(
            'assets/images/mybutton.png',
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
      ),
```