# Flutter: Image.Asset needs up to 2 seconds to load?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this `Button` and 6 `Widgets`, each of them consisting of a `Column` with a `Text` and an `Image.Asset`. Every time this `Button` is pressed, a random one of these 6 `Widgets` is shown. The `Button`and the shown `Widget` are arranged in one `Column`. Why is the image loading time so inconsistant? Sometimes when I press the button, the image is intant loaded, sometimes it takes up to 2 seconds? I want the images to be loaded instant every time the `Button` is pressed so how can I improve the loading time?

Here is the Method I used to get a random Widget shown:

```
class _HomepageState extends State<Homepage> {
  bool isShown = false;

  int randomNumber;

  List<Widget> _widgets = [
    SkillJonglieren(),
    SkillZauberwuerfel(),
    SkillPi(),
    MorseCode(),
    Zeichnen(),
    Schach()
  ];

  var random = new Random();

  void _generateRandomNumber() {
    var random = new Random();

    setState(() => randomNumber = random.nextInt(_widgets.length));
  }
```

And this is the implementation:

```
        body: Container(
          width: 1080,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              gradient: LinearGradient(colors: [Colors.indigo, Colors.red])),
          child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: <Widget>[
                if (isShown == true) _widgets[randomNumber],
                Container(
                    width: 200,
                    height: 70,
                    child: RaisedButton(
```

And I have a second problem: sometimes the button instantly reacts when clicking on It, sometimes I have to click up to three times on It until It reacts. Is there a possibility to solve that problem?

Here is how it looks like (Is there a possibility to make the Image smaller?) :
[image: Here is how it looks like]

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51343735/flutter-image-preload/51343954

Comment: sadly didn't helped