# How to check if screen is fully loaded?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

**Problem**: One of screen in my app has bunch of network images that are being fetched from an API. When user navigates to that screen some images load faster than others, hence users sees a screen that is not fully loaded.

**Expected behaviour**: I want to show a `CircularProgressIndicator` until all the network images are fully loaded.

P.S. Below code doesn't do what I wanted, as it executes the function while images are still loading.

```
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => yourFunction(context));
}
```

Also I am using `SvgPicture.network` from [flutter_svg](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg) package.

Answer (score 0):

```
final Widget networkSvg = SvgPicture.network(
  'https://site-that-takes-a-while.com/image.svg',
  semanticsLabel: 'A shark?!',
  placeholderBuilder: (BuildContext context) => Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
      child: const CircularProgressIndicator()),
);
```

Maybe this could help [Flutter image preload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51343735/flutter-image-preload)

Comment: No, I want to show progress indicator for the whole screen. Sorry if my question was confusing. I have edited my question now.

Comment: Flutter has a mounted event that tells you the widget has been completely loaded.  You can hide your progress indicator on this event and show it on initstate