# Preloading image in flutter clarification

Tags: flutter, dart

I know this question was asked here before: [Flutter image preload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51343735/flutter-image-preload)

Based on this article: https://alex.domenici.net/archive/preload-images-in-a-stateful-widget-on-flutter

I know that you can preload image using this code:

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    image1 = Image.asset("assets/image1.png");
    image2 = Image.asset("assets/image2.png");
    image3 = Image.asset("assets/image3.png");
    image4 = Image.asset("assets/image4.png");
}

@override
void didChangeDependencies() {
  super.didChangeDependencies();

  precacheImage(image1.image, context);
  precacheImage(image2.image, context);
  precacheImage(image3.image, context);
  precacheImage(image4.image, context);
}
```

My question now is why do we need to load the image under `initState` method? The codes under `didChangeDependencies` alone is enough to preload the image right? Like this:

```
@override
void didChangeDependencies() {
  super.didChangeDependencies();

  precacheImage("assets/image1.png", context);
  precacheImage("assets/image2.png", context);
  precacheImage("assets/image3.png", context);
  precacheImage("assets/image4.png", context);
}
```

Comment: Yes, didChangeDependencies is enough in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Loading image under the `initState` is just setting up the instances `image1,...,image4`

As the `precacheImage` requires the `context` (as function argument) to process, that has been moved to `didChangeDependencies`.

Of course, you can move the code from `initState` to `didChangeDependencies`, but as said before it may invoke the code more than once, the necessary set of lines kept in `didChangeDependencies` to access the context.

Comment: Did you read the article I mentioned in my question details If I put the `precacheImage` on the `initState` it will not work. `precacheImage` will only work on `didChangeDependencies`.

Comment: Err! Let me revise and get back.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply. I actually don't need the code in the `initState`, I just want to preload the images using the `precacheImage` function and that function will only work on `didChangeDependencies`. My question is do we need `initState` method? is `didChangeDependencies` enough here?

Comment: Yes, that's enough.

Comment: Hi, I want to clarify that `precacheImage` can work on `initState` with `WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback`