# how to make the image loading faster in flutter app?

Tags: flutter, dart

this is code of mainbody of my flutter application and image in the start take a little bit time to load. I have bolded the font which is having image builder.
I've made kind of image slider at the start of app having three images that changes when we slide but it takes too much time to load even I compressed the size of image also but that didn't work.

```
import 'package:daily_expense/constants.dart';
import 'package:daily_expense/screens/sign_in/login_screen.dart';
import 'package:daily_expense/screens/sign_up/sign_up_screen.dart';
import 'package:daily_expense/size_config.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../../../components/login_button.dart';
import '../../../components/signup_button.dart';
import 'splash_content.dart';

class mainBody extends StatefulWidget {
  const mainBody({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

@override
State<mainBody> createState() => _mainBodyState();
}

class _mainBodyState extends State<mainBody> {
int currentPage = 0;//images
List<Map<String, String>> splashData = [
{"image": "assets/images/welcome1.jpg"},//need fix 
{"image": "assets/images/welcome2.jpg"},//need fix
{"image": "assets/images/welcome3.jpg"}//need fix
];

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return SafeArea(
  child: SizedBox(
    width: double.infinity,
    child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          flex: 3,
          child: **PageView.builder(
            onPageChanged: (value) {
              setState(() {
                currentPage = value;
              });
            },
            itemCount: splashData.length,
            //I've used itemBuider to show 3 images in sliding format
            itemBuilder: (context, index) => SpalshContent(
              image: splashData[index]["image"],//need fix maybe
            ),
          )**,
        ),
        Expanded(
          flex: 2,
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                horizontal: getProportionateScreenWidth(25)),
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Spacer(),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: List.generate(
                      splashData.length, (index) => buildDot(index: index)),
                ),
                Spacer(),
                LoginButton(
                  text: 'Login',
                  press: () {
                    Navigator.pushNamed(context, LoginScreen.routeName);
                  },
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: getProportionateScreenHeight(20),
                ),
                SignupButton(
                  text: 'Sign Up',
                  press: () {Navigator.pushNamed(context, SignupScreen.routeName);},
                ),
                Spacer()
              ],
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
}


//this is animated container for dot change on change of photo
AnimatedContainer buildDot({int? index}) {
return AnimatedContainer(
  duration: kAnimationDuration,
  margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 5),
  height: 6,
  width: currentPage == index ? 20 : 6,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: currentPage == index ? kPrimaryColor : Color(0xff607d8b),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(3)),
      );
    }
  }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter image preload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51343735/flutter-image-preload)