# Flutter carousel with lazy loading/pagination

Tags: flutter

I am learning flutter and have got this to work with my backend:

https://pub.dev/packages/infinite_scroll_pagination

But it had the problem that it would not prefetch the images, I tried to prefetch them but I failed. They would only display when they appeared on the screen, so then I found this package:

https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider

That has a built in example that prefetch the images and overall works great, except that I have not got it to work with my backend, and I am not sure if it supports lazy loading etc.

I am looking for more general advice for how to proceed here. Would it be easier to implement lazy loading in the carousel_slider, or to get prefetch/render to work in infinite_scroll_pagination? Is the pre-render trivial, or is it something that is in general very hard to get working? I really want this to work but I have been stuck for days and really need some help for how to spend my time wisely

Answer (score 1):

There is one specific package which has `PageView` widget with prefetching pages which is [preload_page_view](https://pub.dev/packages/preload_page_view).

But if you want the cool Carousel effects, you could maybe refer to [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51343735/flutter-image-preload) on stack overflow, which uses `precacheImage` function like so:

```dart
class MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    // Adjust the provider based on the image type
    precacheImage(new AssetImage('...'));
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

}
```